# Should FreeLAN or other projects pay Stack Exchange for redirecting support to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

It appears FreeLAN has outsourced its support to Stack Overflow: [How to set up freelan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29874016).

How does Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange go about signing them up as a client? -Is there an internal sales team that makes a connection in these cases?

Related, how are things priced? Is there a fixed, monthly cost? Or do they pay per-question?

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't have such a business model. There are no relationships between companies and Stack Exchange when they outsource their support.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're serious, but the only related thing which exists on SO are _sponsored tags_ where companies like MS or FB pay to have their icon on the tag. It would however be a good idea to reach out to Freelan and get them to clarify the instructions related to SO on their [support page](http://www.freelan.org/get_help.html#).

Comment: Also see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: See the [tag:outsourcing] tag for examples of posts where the community team is being asked to reach out to a company or group to help them communicate better about what is suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: To build on the comments from @MartijnPieters: the [FreeLAN site does advise users to use Stack Overflow](http://www.freelan.org/get_help.html) (*"A good way of getting help is to ask your question on Stack Overflow, by tagging it #freelan."*), but they explicitly say in the next sentence that SO is not their official support channel. (Their official support channel is a mailing list.)

Comment: @Martijn - *"There are no relationships between companies and Stack Exchange when they outsource their support..."* - that's too bad. It seems like a potential source of revenue. If the network is already doing the work, then they should consider getting paid for it. Professional services don't even need to guarantee results. Just look at any retainer you sign with a lawyer.

Comment: @jww: and how'd that work? "don't put a link on your site until you paid us"? Stack Exchange gains value from people visiting and using the site and contributing quality content; it doesn't matter how they found the site.

Comment: @Martijn - *"... and how would that work?"* - yep, you can tell programmers run the Stack Exchange network... Are the programmers paid with [caffeine and pizza](https://www.zazzle.com/programmer_definition_t_shirt-235878094715752076)?

Comment: I think @MartijnPieters is asking *what possible benefit* a company would get from paying Stack Exchange. Any company can already link to SO and direct their user there; Stack Exchange can't stop them from doing that. They can't pay Stack Exchange for users to answer their tag's questions. the only possible thing I think of is paying for the privilege for their tag to contain bad, off-topic support questions on it, which sounds like a disaster of an idea.

Comment: Maybe a company could pay SO to give a consultation on how to direct their users to SO ("Did we get everything right when listing what's on topic?") to ensure their users don't get a nasty shock when their question is downvoted and closed, but it's already in SO's best interests to give that out that advice for free anyway (since it makes SO regulars happier not to have to deal with bad questions).

Comment: @jww: no, it simply doesn't fit with the *very successful* free and open model that made Stack Overflow what it is today. Not that Stack Exchange didn't try to provide additional value to companies, but that [hasn't worked out so well so far](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186850/facebook-partnership-and-subsite-no-more). This is entirely aside from the fact that FreeLAN is not a commercial entity but an OSS project.

Answer (score 23):

I am the author of freelan and to put things straight: I plead guilty.

I initialy put that recommendation at a time where it was not uncommon to see questions about OpenVPN's configuration for instance, and those were usually well received. Things have changed as the Stack Exchange networks grew and such questions are obviously no longer a good fit (I suppose [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) might be better in this case).

My apologies if this caused any trouble: **the recommendation needs to go**, there is no doubt.

<s>I will remove it and the link to SO this evening (I can't do it before sadly).</s>

I [updated the offending recommendation](http://freelan.org/get_help.html#) with:

> The official way to get help, is to write to the users mailing-list at
>   users@freelan.org. Registering is easy and straighforward, as well as
>   unregistering.
>
> You may also choose to ask your question on Super User, by tagging it
>   freelan. If you do so, please make sure you first read the FAQ and
>   that your question is on-topic before you ask anything. Keep in mind
>   that Super User is not the official FreeLAN support channel and that
>   you may get no answer.

All that being said, I find the harsh tone of the question unfair: I spend hours every day responding to my users on the official mailing-list. I don't get a single dime for it (actually, it costs me $500/year in hosting, not to mention sucking all my free time). I mainly wanted to give to people less at ease with mailing-lists an opportunity to use another medium for their questions (and a great one I know give quality answers). I can see how this became wrong, but it was **not** done out of cheapness.

Honestly, between this and the insult emails I get from time to time because people feel they are entitled an answer in 10 minutes, I really wonder what keeps people from giving up on open source.

Comment: The tone of the question is also completely off-base and reflects more on the OP and their misunderstanding of how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: As someone with nearly 600 open issues on one of my GitHub repositories and 700 questions about it on Stack Overflow, I sympathize. Angry emails, Twitter messages, and constant support requests sure do take a toll after a while. Well-asked questions on the Stack Exchange network can help to cut down on this by providing a public reference for frequently asked questions. As long as the questions themselves are appropriate for the site, there isn't a huge problem with people finding support here.

Answer (score 15):

[We have very clear guidance on how communities can be supported on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). The folks behind Freelan *might not* have seen it. It's .. complicated, much more so than many would expect.

There is no service surrounding allowing companies or projects to support the needs of their developers on Stack Overflow. That's something that happens quite organically; as Stack Overflow users use something new, they naturally want to bring their questions about it to the site. That is *fine*, and we encourage them to do so.

It's also fine if someone wants to send users to Stack Overflow to ask programming questions about their product or project - as long as they give very clear guidance on how to do it, and are (themselves) actively monitoring tags that their customers / users would apply.

I'll research this and reach out to Freelan to get better guidance in place on their end. I'm sure it's not intentional, but it needs correcting.