# Should the [Rocket.Chat] tag be removed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

The [Rocket.Chat](https://rocket.chat/) project is pointing to Stack Overflow for part of their support, as it can be seen from the [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket.chat) on Stack Overflow and from their [contact page](https://rocket.chat/contact) pointing to the [rocket.chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket.chat) tag on Stack Overflow.

I was wondering how this tag could be legitimate on Stack Overflow since it's more about installation troubleshooting rather than anything related to development.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/2675154)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is [allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235097/158100) that a (small) Open Source project or [company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254251/578411) has a tag on Stack Overflow. So let's not base our judgement based on that.

You're right that most questions seem to be around the installation and configuration of the that tool which is off-topic. Some question though seem to be about integrating that product with other tool stacks. Most of those lack an MCVE but they are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

My advice would be:

- reach out to Rocket Chat and have them provide clearer guidance which type of questions can be asked at Stack Overflow. Additionally they should provide directions how to make sure the questions asked fit our minimal quality standards. The [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) might be useful.
- Clean-up (that is edit, vote and flag) all current posts in that tag to help the Rocket Chat crew in keeping their tag clean. It doesn't look like any of their top answers have enough privileges to moderate their tag accordingly.
- Help them a bit with the wiki-excerpt, by removing the roaring marketing speech:

  > Use this tag for questions regarding the deployment, configuration, maintenance, architecture or general coding help of https://rocket.chat, an open-source web server/client chat application. For questions about general use, not development or programming, use https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues.

  The tag wiki should also start with and focus on the usage guidance, what to include in a question, how an small example with code can be created, link to some good questions maybe even add some frequently asked questions and move the marketing stuff to the end or maybe even off-site.

I see no reason yet to burninate that tag and I hope passers-by will not take this on. If things don't improve I suggest we ask [Tim Post to reach out to them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291581/578411).

Comment: i had a go at all the questions / answers to flag / vote some of them

Comment: Thank you for this! I work for the Rocket.Chat team and will be editing the rocket.chat tag wiki shortly.

Comment: I've edited our wiki and it has now been approved. Could you guys please let me know if there's anything else I should do to make sure we follow SO guidelines? We at Rocket.Chat are all relatively new to SO, so any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MarceloSchmidt you improved the wiki and excerpt a bit. I have updated my answer with how I would have structured it. If you have questions that are currently open in your tag but should be closed, please [flag them for closure](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). If you need some help to get the questions really closed, feel free to ping me in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: I can also do the tag wiki edit for you, if you're Ok with that

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with [the 4 criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) (this was in the pop-up box when you added the `burninate-request` tag)

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   The excerpt looks fine. There's no wiki.

   > Rocket.Chat is a widely deployed, open source, chat and collaboration platform created using JavaScript. Use this tag for questions regarding deployment, configuration, maintenance, architecture or general coding help.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** I don't know that the tag itself is off-topic. SO can be used for helping in setting up and running software, as long as you're not looking solely for OS-level help. Also, it looks like you can integrate it to work with your own software, so that would be on topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** Yes. It's specific to the software.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** Again, yes.

So I don't think this is a good candidate for burnination. That having been said, looking through the 18 questions, very few of them are good questions. Most, in fact, are close/deletion worthy. There's a lot of cleanup to be done. But I did see a couple of questions that looked good enough to keep the tag.

Comment: i agree that very few are good questions and on top of that, very few actually belong to SO in my opinion. they are more issues or install problems for SuperUser or ServerFault

Answer (score 6):

it's Gabriel Engel here, founder of Rocket.Chat

We will take a look at the articles linked here and will make our best to adjust to the guidelines.

Thanks for the information!